# Copy first attribute's value, then create new attribute with value of first attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs with an attribute called `name`:

```
<div name="SCENE_I">SCENE_I</div>
<div name="SCENE_II">SCENE_II</div>
<div name="SCENE_III">SCENE_III</div>
```

How can I copy the values of the name attribute, then create a new attribute called `groupName` for each div, and copy the values of the `name` attribute to the new `groupName` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all `div` using `each()` method and add attribute `groupName` like following.

```
$('div[name]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('groupName', $(this).attr('name'));
});
```